# Как сделать рекурсивный ptrace?

Tags: c++, linux, c

Имеется процесс, который много раз форкается и запускает множество процессов. Те, в свою очередь, запускают свои процессы дочерние, не делая их trace-инга. Нужно из главного процесса trace-ить ВСЕ дочерние процессы до единого через ptrace. Да, именно ptrace, программно, не `/usr/bin/strace`. Не подскажете, как такое реализовать? Т. е., должно быть так:

```
main // Trace all processes and subprocesses,
by multithread...
|- process1
|-|- subprocess1
|-|- subprocess2
|- process2
```

Мне просто надо программно реализовать `/usr/bin/strace -f`... Язык - C++ (можно и сугубо C реализацию).

Comment: А что тебе мешает получить информацию через pipe?

Comment: не совсем пойму, о чем вы. Я хочу сделать рекурсивный ptrace ПРОГРАММНО, без `system()` и `exec[lvpe]()`

Comment: Я тебе про pipe говорю :) man popen

Comment: а, `popen()`...